# Как отправить с js в html

Tags: javascript

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return updateVarss();">
</form>
function updateVarss(){
 return confirm("Вы подтверждаете удаление?");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
 updateVars();
});
```

Не получается передать с js на диалоговое окно, т.е. теперь окно совсем пропало.....

Comment: @dimas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я в одном из проектов вешал обработчик клика на кнопку удаления, может, и вам подойдёт.
[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/88wx46gh/)

HTML

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить?')" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ну я так тоже могу, мне нужно именно через js, т.к. там потом будет ещё считывать выбранную информацию и передавать на диологовое окно)

Comment: Ну, вы напишите всю логику, которую хотите сделать, а чтобы ваш исходный код заработал, нужно вот так сделать: http://jsfiddle.net/88wx46gh/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/88wx46gh/3/

получилось, но при отмене все равно продолжает работать и когда ставлю ваш код предыдущий перестает работать(